# Как избежать jQuery, когда нужен ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Мне не нравится использовать jQuery. (Сугубо эстетические мотивы и мой перфекционизм заставляют меня избегать фреймворков и писать на чистом языке).

Но, сами понимаете, - писать ajax на без jQuery - ещё хуже. Там очень много буков, в которых нужно разобраться.
Есть ли способ подключить к своему скрипту только ajax из jQuery? Может кто-то где то вырезал эту часть jQuery?

Если такого нигде нет, не могли бы вы подсказать какие нибудь уроки/статьи/курсы, в которых можно понять - как писать ajax на чистом js. Спасибо.

Comment: В `fetch` нужно очень мало букв

Comment: ещё есть [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь нужно научиться сериализовывать данные.
Ниже приведена упрощённая реализация, не поддерживающая многократно вложенные данные.
Лучше всего взять готовую реализацию, например, `$.param` из того же jQuery

Далее воспроизводим обычный сниппет ajax вызова. Обработка результатов может быть разной, тут я использовал стандартный для nodejs callback-style, с сигнатурой `function next(error, result)`.

```js
function ajaxPost(uri, data, next) {
  function serialize(data) {
    var parts = [];
    for (var k in data) {
      if (Array.isArray(data[k])) {
        parts.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + '[]=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]))
      } else if (typeof data[k] === 'object') {
        for (var objk in data[k]) parts.push(encodeURIComponent(k + '[' + objk + ']') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k][objk]))

      } else {
        parts.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]))
      }
    }
    return parts.join('&');
  }
  // Далее стандартный сниппет:
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        next(null, xhr.responseText);
      } else {
        next(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(serialize(data));
}

ajaxPost('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  max: 5,
  min: 2,
  list: [1, 2, 5],
  obj: {a: 'some', b: 42}
}, function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(res);
})
```

---

Если вы не ограничены поддержкой старых браузеров, рекомендую всё же использовать новый синтаксис `fetch`.
Сериализация всё ещё остаётся на вашей совести, в данном примере я демонстрирую json:

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({a: 7, str: 'Some string: &=&'})
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался таки в ajax без jQuery (немного).
Для своих целей сделал такую функцию:

```
var ajax = function (requestObject) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                requestObject.success(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.open("POST", requestObject.direction, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        data = "min=" + requestObject.min + "&max=" + requestObject.max;
        request.send(data);
    }
```

И вызов:

```
button.onclick = function () {
            ajax({
                direction: "num.php",
                min: document.querySelector("#min").value,
                max: document.querySelector("#max").value,
                success: function (data) {
                    document.querySelector("#res").innerHTML = data;
                }
            });         
        }
```

Чем то напоминает функцию jQuery, но эта только для моих целей, совсем не гибкая. Если поработать над ней, то можно сделать универсальную функцию, которую можно будет использовать где угодно. (А мне пока этого зватит)

Comment: Куча глобальных переменных, жёстко заданные параметры. Вы уверены, что это стоило показывать?